# When do I need to renew my Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

I have an active Schengen visa which expires in June this year. However, I will be traveling to Greece at the end of July and will need to renew my visa. My question is- by when do I need to apply for a new Schengen visa? Can I do it while the existing visa is still active or do I need to cancel it and apply for a new one OR Do i have to wait for it to expire before I can apply again?

Answer (score 2):

The usual rule applies, i.e. you should apply about three months before the trip. If your visa is still valid but will expire before your next trip it's not a problem, your new visa will simply not be valid immediately but only for the dates of your trip. The only thing that consulate want to avoid is overlapping *periods of validity*.

For multiple-entry visas (apparently your case?), you can even apply earlier (up to six months in advance) and should get a visa with a period of validity starting right after that of your current visa. With visas like that, it's even possible to plan a trip spanning two visas (entering on one visa, leaving on another) as long as there is no gap between them (and of course [you don't stay too long in the Schengen area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)).